# Active admin In Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin

I have Rails 4 app, which I want to manage with Active admin. I have 2 models,

- Item
- Category

`Item` has 2 fields, `name` and `category_id`. The `Category` model has a field called `name`. The models are related with `has_many :items` and `belongs_to :Category`.

When I try to access the admin panel in Active Admin, after configuring some aspect in Active Admin, in the model Item I have a desplegable menu with the `id` reference of the `category` like this  #Category:=0x675654. What I want is to get the name of the category. How can I to do this? I don't have access to edit this view.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Item do
  form do |f|
    f.inputs "Item" do
      f.input :category, as: :select, collection: Category.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id] }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This work but the form only show this field. This not show the Item name field. Sorry, I,m not expert in Active-admin

Comment: Glad you've got it sorted out. Would you mind accepting the answer then?

Comment: yes but i cant vote because this require 15 reputation points. Sorry. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to show the name in the index page, you need to customize it with something like:

```
column 'Name' do |item|
  name = Category.find(item.category_id).name
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To simply display the name :

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Item do
  menu parent: 'My Menu'
    index do
      id_column
      column 'Category' do |item|
        item.category.name
      end
    end
  end
```

If you'd like to get a link to the resource on top of that name, use `auto_link` :

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Item do
  menu parent: 'My Menu'
    index do
      id_column
      column 'Category' do |item|
        auto_link(item.category, item.category.name)
      end
    end
  end
```

The same thing applies for Item views.